structured inline enumerate problem latex
I am writing a book with a lot of tests with multiple choices. And I use inline enumerate. But it looks random and weird. I want it to look correct like in the first problem. If the answers are moved to the second line, so that they are also correctly distributed along the line and in line with the previous line. How can I automate this process for a large book? Below is a minimal version of the book
\documentclass[10pt,a5paper]{book}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\makeatletter
\AddEnumerateCounter{\asbuk}{\russian@alph}{}
\makeatother
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb, gensymb,amsthm}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[chapter]
\newtheorem{problem}[thm]{Problem}
\setlist[enumerate]{label=\asbuk*),ref=\asbuk*,itemjoin=\hspace{25pt},
align = left, labelwidth = \parindent, leftmargin = \parindent}


\begin{document}


\setcounter{chapter}{1}
\section*{Sec 1}

\begin{problem}
    Bla bla
    
    \begin{enumerate*}
        \item 8
        \item 12
        \item 20
        \item 30
        \item 40
        \item 60

    \end{enumerate*}
\end{problem}

\begin{problem}
    Bla bla

    \begin{enumerate*}
        \item 62000000
        \item 63000000
        \item 64000000
        \item 72000000
        \item 74000000
        \item 81000000
    \end{enumerate*}
\end{problem}

\begin{problem}
    Bla bla

    \begin{enumerate*}
        \item большим
        \item указательным
        \item средним
        \item безымянным
        \item мизинцем
        \item невозможно определить
    \end{enumerate*}
\end{problem}

\begin{problem}
    Bla bla

    \begin{enumerate*}[itemjoin=\hspace{25pt}]
        \item 6\%
        \item 15\%
        \item 23\%
        \item 25\%
        \item 31\%
        \item 46\%
    \end{enumerate*}
\end{problem}

\begin{problem}
    Bla bla

    \begin{enumerate*}
        \item Понедельник
        \item Вторник
        \item Среда
        \item Четверг
        \item Пятница
        \item Суббота
    \end{enumerate*}
\end{problem}


\end{document}



Try the tasks package.
